# AVFoundation saving Photo in-app is 3-4 times larger than saving using the Photos app

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I using AVFoundation to capture photos and to save the photos locally.

I get the data using AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation, but the file size seems to be 3-4x compared to the size when saving using the Photos framework. How can this be?

photoData:

```
photoData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer)
```

Code saving using Photos Framework:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({ [unowned self] in
    let creationRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: UIImage(data: photoData)!)
    creationRequest.creationDate = Date()

    if let assetCollection = assetCollection, let assetPlaceholder = creationRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset {
        let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: assetCollection)
        let enumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceholder]

        albumChangeRequest?.addAssets(enumeration)
    }

    }, completionHandler: { [unowned self] success, error in
    }
)
```

Code saving locally:

```
try! photoData.write(to: originalFilePath, options: .atomic)
```

photoData is just Data.

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: I added some code :)

Comment: Interesting. Can you show how you know the sizes in question?

Comment: I basically just import the photos from the camera roll and inspect the size and do the same with the photo saved locally.